# Может ли sprintf() завершиться с ошибкой?

Tags: c

Не могу найти конкретики. В манах есть описание для целой группы функций *printf. Указано, что возвращается либо число напечатаных символов, либо отрицательное значение в случае ошибки. Более того, списка errno не приводится как для других функций, отсюда ещё большее недопонимание ситуации. Те, которые работают с файловым дескриптором - с ними более-менее понятно, но те, которые работают с буфером ( в том числе sprintf ), с ними у меня нет чёткой ясности, в каких случаях может произойти ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, может, если ошибка произойдет при преобразованиии многобайтовых символов в однобайтовую кодировку (я много чего попробовал, кажется, это единственный источник возможной ошибки для `sprintf`):

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
    wchar_t c = 128;
    char buffer[100];
    if (sprintf(buffer, "%lc", c) < 0) {
        printf("error\n");
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O temp.c && ./a.out
> error
> ```

Цитата из [стандарта](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> 3. number of characters written to buffer (not counting the
>    terminating null character), or a negative value if an encoding error
>    (for string and character conversion specifiers) occurred

Comment: А если попробовать распечатать строку длиной `INT_MAX + 1` символов?

Comment: [Maximum size of string can be printed using %s?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27800706)

Comment: У меня, в `Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia  5.4.0-107-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux  gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` **`sprintf(buf, NULL);`**  также возвращает **-1**

Comment: `sprintf(buf, NULL)` — это UB.

Comment: @wololo, возможно (хотя в manpage про это ни слова, и у меня errno совершенно ожидаемое -- `Invalid argument`)